# Proving $\prod_{t=1}^{T}\sqrt{1-4x_t^{2}}\leq \exp\left(-2\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t^{2}\right)$, given $1-x\leq \exp(-x)$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

> Given that $1-x\leq \exp{(-x)}$, prove that
>
> $$\prod_{t=1}^{T}\sqrt{1-4x_t^{2}}\leq \exp\left(-2\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t^{2}\right)$$

How would one approach this problem. Without the square root I know that

$$1-2\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t^{2}\leq \exp(-2\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_t^{2})$$

But I'm not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $t$, using the hint, we have
$$1-(2x_t)^2\leq \exp\bigg(-(2x_t)^2\bigg)$$
Thus
$$1-4x_t^2\leq \exp(-4x^2_t)$$
Take the square root on each side
$$\sqrt{1-4x_t^2}\leq \exp(-2x^2_t)$$
Multiplying all these inequalities for $1\leq t\leq T$ yields

$$\prod_{t=1}^T\sqrt{1-4x_t^2}\leq \prod_{t=1}^T\exp(-2x^2_t)$$

In other words
$$\prod_{t=1}^T\sqrt{1-4x_t^2}\leq \exp(-2  \sum_{t=1}^T x^2_t)$$

Comment: wow..brilliant. i forgot how the square root can get pushed into the exponent

Comment: can you explain this $\sqrt{1-4x_t^2}\leq \exp(-2x^2_t)$ How did you get $-2x^2_t$ Shouldnt x^2 become x